# Caliburn.Micro and ContextMenu for DataGrid Row

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a `ContextMenu` in WPF `DataGridRow`.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="RowContextMenu">
    <MenuItem cal:Message.Attach="SomeMethod()"/>
</ContextMenu>
<Style x:Key="RowWithContextMenu" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowContextMenu}" />
</Style>
```

Each row in `DataGrid` represents an individual view-model class instance. Let's call it `RowViewModel`. When I click the menu item, `SomeMethod()` is executed and everything is OK for the first time, but clicking menu item on other rows executes `SomeMethod()` for the row where `ContextMenu` was shown for the first time.

I put some breakpoints in CM's `ActionMessage.cs` source code and found out that clicking the right mouse button to show menu for the first time invokes event calling `ElementLoaded()` method which in turn calls `UpdateContext()`. So context *(it is `RowViewModel`)* is created for menu item but it is never re-assigned when calling context menu on other rows.

Comment: Is `SomeMethod()` defined on `RowViewModel` instances or on the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` itself ?

Comment: `SomeMethod()` is defined on `RowViewModel` instances. If I define `SomeMethod(RowViewModel rowModel)` and pass `$dataContext` to it (`<MenuItem cal:Message.Attach="SomeMethod($dataContext)"/>`) then it comes with the rigth value (`$dataContext` represents the view model of appropriate row) although instance itself is the one of the row where ContextMenu was shown for the first time.

Comment: Tracking your issue to find the source of the problem needs some work which I don't really have time for but I can give you another way which may achieve what you want and it is *- from my opinion-* more elegant, let me know if you're interested.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested. Any assistance is welcome.

Comment: Found the solution [here](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/discussions/69605)

Answer (score 3):

You should take advantage of the bubbling feature of [Action Messages](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions&referringTitle=Documentation) to handle this more easily and elegantly.

Instead of putting `SomeMethod()` on each `RowViewModel` instance, you should put it on the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid` itself, then change `SomeMethod()` signature so i takes a `RowViewModel` as a parameter which is of course the `DataContext` of each row, so now it looks like this `SomeMethod(RowViewModel rowViewModel)` and then use `cal:Message.Attach="SomeMethod($dataContext)"` in XAML.

After that you should configure the `ContextMenu` so that it sends the action messages bubbling to it so that they reach the `DataContext`  of the `DataGrid` but this this tricky and requires some looking around.

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883975/wpf-treeview-contextmenu-datacontext) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668554/treeview-contextmenu-not-fired-events) to learn more about doing it.